# Thresholding Images and noise

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm doing a binary thresholding on an image using opencv, while moving or animating for example a circle on a binary image, there are few noise that appears around the moveable object. An image to illustrate what I mean is attached. How can I get rid of those artifacts?
[image]

Comment: Does OpenCV have a way of determining which bits are connected? If so, maybe all connected bits that aren't circular could be eliminated?

Comment: Extrapolating off user1118321's idea, you could find the bounds of the circle, then cull outside of that.

Comment: Is that artifact due to frame differencing?  You mentioned that it's a moving circle.  If so, try 3-frame differencing.  It goes like this: `f = abs((frame1 - frame0) * (frame1 - frame2))`

Comment: Yes due to drame differencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to apply several cycles of the erosion algorithm (until there is only one object left) followed by same number of  cycles of the dilation algorithm (the erosion/dilation pair is called opening)

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of object that are non circles, you can filter contours according to several metrics [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_factor_%28image_analysis_and_microscopy%29) seems to be a good starting link.
In your case, you could find all contours and keep only the ones with a high circularity and a small aspect ratio.
You can go further and calculates metrics such as area/area_of_the_convex_hull. This one should be one for your circle.

Good luck

ps: [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEAQFjAA&url=http://morse.cs.byu.edu/650/lectures/lect08/regions.slides.printing.6.pdf&ei=6nUZUJWsPMj80QWHvYDIBg&usg=AFQjCNF9saSnoN6Jshllf-5MpgioXxDhMw) pdf seems more exhaustive.